# My PHP file is not getting executed

Tags: php, mysql

I created a .php file and when I am trying to execute it via- localhost, it shows nothing. If the script is working fine, then it should print something on the screen. <- The basic idea of the script, but nothing is getting displayed.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","somanshu","somanshu");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("james007", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  if($_POST['mail'] == $row['email'])
  {
  echo "Logged In.<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" CONTENT=\"0;URL=home\">";
  }
  else
  {
  $sql="INSERT INTO info (email, password)
  VALUES
  ('$_POST[mail]','$_POST[pwd]')";
   if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
   {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   else
   {
   echo "Added. <META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" CONTENT=\"0;URL=home\">";
   }
  }
  }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You are using a soon-to-be-removed API. Use PDO or MySQLi, not ext/mysql, or you will suddenly find that your code doesn't work. Also, it's famously insecure due to lack of proper(ly used) escaping and lack of prepared statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that there is data in the database to select. If `SELECT * FROM info` returns no rows, this script will not output anything.

Comment: This works. Actually, I emptied my table ( via TRUNCATE method. ) Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` and see if its give errors.

add below code at top of the page.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

if its still not display errors then try

```
mysqli_select_db("james007", $con)or die(mysqli_error());
```

Also check

```
mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM info")or die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: I meant code doesn't looks broke, if someone likes to ignore official warnings from PHP team, that's a bit about personal preferences. Of course it's better to switch to PDO or mysqli

Comment: Thanks for the information. If that API is going down, its good to change our approach right now.

Answer (score 0):

First things first:
Is php executed at all? To find out create a file called test.php and write

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

inside.

If this is not working you have to set up php for your webserver properly.

Comment: `phpinfo()` not `php_info()` I can't edit your post as it's not a big enough edit.

Comment: Sorry, doing this from memory while in the hospital :-)